# iPhone XR not showing bottomAppBar with correct height

Tags: ios, iphone, dart, flutter

I have integrated bottomAppBar with my Flutter app and added FAB with it. But that is not showing me correctly. Please check attached image:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a SafeArea? https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Widget inside SafeArea :

```
return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        ...
      ),
    );
```

More info here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html